# Difference between WebSocketHandler and WebSocketServlet

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I am setting up a WebSocket handler using Jetty 9.
I have seen examples using either WebSocketHandler or WebSocketServlet.

Here is what I am doing:

```
public class WebSocketServer{
  public WebSocketServer(){ 
    WebSocketHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
      @Override
      public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.register(MyWebSocketHandler.class);
      }
    };
  }
}

@WebSocket
public class MyWebSocketHandler{...}
```

Here is what they are doing:
(taken from http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-server-api.html)

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyEcho WebSocket Servlet", urlPatterns = { "/echo" })
public class MyEchoServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
    factory.register(MyEchoSocket.class);
  }
}
```

What is the actual difference and what would be the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 2 choices reflect the 2 fundamental techniques people use when writing applications for Jetty.

`WebSocketHandler` are part of the more fundamental **Handlers** technique of organizing a web application.  These Handlers very basic and represent the fundamental building block of request handling in Jetty.  At its heart, the Server has only 1 Handler to deal with (aka `Server.setHandler(Handler)`).

There are many built-in Handlers that provide mechanisms to organize your Handler(s).  As an example of some of this variety (tip of the iceberg), you could have more than 1 Handlers by using a [`HandlerList`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerList.html), wrap Handlers in [`HandleWrapper`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerWrapper.html) to have optional behavior based on request details, specify Context's for then using [`ContextHandler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html) inside of a [`ContextHandlerCollection`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandlerCollection.html), etc.. (with far too many combinations to lay out in an answer on StackOverflow)

`WebSocketServlet` is the higher level way to organize a web application, configured entirely within the Servlet spec and standard.  Complete with all of their standards for annotations, filters, listeners, behavior, etc.

People pick and choose usually one technique or the other.  Both are just as capable, just as performant.  Neither is a better choice over the other.

It is usually wise to choose one technique over the other and sticking with that technique for your entire webapp, as mixing the 2 behaviors is tricky and full of landmines of unexpected behavior.

*Note: architecturally speaking, the Servlet layer itself is a Jetty Handler, either via the [`ServletContextHandler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.html) or the [`WebAppContext`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html) (which is just a specialized ServletContextHandler).*